# Регистрация нового пользователя SQL

Tags: php, sql

Интересует вопрос, в чем заключается моя ошибка при написании Query запроса на добавления пользователя в БД? Буду рад ответу с объяснением.

Форма логирования которая работает:

```
if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login']=="LOGIN"){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin where user='".$_POST['user']."' and password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  sleep(1.5);
  $log = $stmt->rowCount();

} else {
  $log=0;
}
```

Форма регистрации которая **отказывается** работать:

(Подозреваю свою ошибку в составлении запроса Query)

```
if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login']=="REGISTER"){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user, password) VALUES ('".$_POST['login']."', '".md5($_POST['password'])."')";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  //session_start();
  unset($_SESSION['name']); 
  sleep(1.5);
  $log = $stmt->rowCount();

} else {
  $log=0;
}
```

Сама форма и баттоны Login/Register. Напомню что все действия логирования и регистрации производятся с одной формы, нужные параметры и взаимодействия передаются с помощью `button`.

```
<div class="loginform">
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Username: </td>
        <td><input name="user" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password: </td>
        <td><input name="password" type="password"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
     <input type="submit"name="login" value="LOGIN"> 
     <input type="submit" name="register" value="REGISTER">
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Созданная таблица в phpMyAdmin именно для регистрации.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите значение переменной $sql после подстановки в неё параметров.

Comment: @Akina буду признателен если подскажите как это сделать)

Comment: зачем Вы на сервер отправляете необработанный `$_POST` ? суть [подготавливаемых запросов](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) в том, чтобы отправить шаблон запроса, а не запрос с непроверенными данными, кои должны быть использованы в [bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: `$log = $stmt->rowCount();` будет 0, т.к. при `insert` вы не затронули ни 1 строку. [информация о функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.rowcount.php). Для проверки успешной записи достаточно `if($stmt) return "success";` или `$conn->lastInsertId();` если нужен `id` последнего `insert`

Comment: *как это сделать* да тупо после присвоения echo-нуть его куда-нибудь или в файл записать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Никогда не отправляйте на сервер непроверенные данные! Суть `prepare()` в [подготовке к запросу](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), для чего на сервер отправляется шаблон запроса.
2. [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.rowcount.php) - возвращает количество строк, **затронутых** последним SQL-запросом. Вы добавляете строки, поэтому достаточно проверки на успешность запроса.

Как должно быть:

```
if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login']=="REGISTER" && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
    if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql))){
        echo __LINE__ ." - не удалось подготовить запрос (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
        die; //не зачем дальше идти если ошибка
    }
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['login'], md5($_POST['password']));
    $stmt->execute();
    if(!$stmt)
    {
        echo __LINE__ ." - не удалось выполнить запрос (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
        die;
    }

    $log = 1; //т.к. у Вас добавляется одна запись и если дошли до этой строки, значит ошибок нет
    //session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
    sleep(1.5); //зачем ?
    //$log = $stmt->rowCount(); будет 0 если запрос INSERT не затрагивает строки
    //если нужен id записи, то $log = $conn->lastInsertId();
}
else
{
    $log=0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо что объяснили, понял свою ошибку )

Comment: Может подскажите почему вылетает ошибка? Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() на линии где "$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['user'], ($_POST['password']));" . Почему undefined ?

Comment: Т.к я использую PDO я думаю нужен другой стейтмент.

Comment: @OlegSevernuy из ошибки следует, что Вы используете PDO, Вам нужно использовать не bind_param(), а [bindParam()](http://php.net/PDOStatement.bindParam), в мануале есть примеры

Comment: Все заработало когда изменил на  $stmt->bindParam. Все верно. Спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 1):

Если опустить безопасность данных операций, то ошибка скорее всего в том, что тут пост `$_POST['login']`, а не `$_POST['user']`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user, password) VALUES ('".$_POST['login']."', '".md5($_POST['password'])."')";
```